# How to add pagination in elastic search aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search,

doing R&D on 
version is :1.2.2 and 1.3.2

both producing the same set of result for my millions of records.

My question is I am doing term aggregation in a query for producing  result.In my requirement I need to paginate the record from 0 to 10 and 10 to 11.

Any suggestions on this ? how can I do this.

And also I can't able to find difference between 1.2.2 and 1.3.2 version,any refering document can be more helpful.

Comment: There is a [discussion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) about this topic. looks like it is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `size` and `from` while querying

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/pagination.html

```
{
  "from":0,         
  "size":50
}
```